# My question is about the return type of a class member function as a pointer to class

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a question about return type of a function as a pointer to class that how it works. Especially `treenode* get_left()`

```
class treenode{
private:
   int object;
   treenode* left;
   treenode* right;

public:
   treenode* get_left(){
      return this->left;
   }
};
```

Comment: Okay, that's what your question is about. But what is the question? What is it you don't understand *specifically*?

Answer (score 0):

This function returns a pointer of type Treenode which have 3 attributes: int object, treenode* left and treenode* right.

You can use this pointer as object and call their function.

That is to say, if you have the following tree:

```
        6 
     4     9
```

if you do : SixTree.get_left() it returns a pointer to treenode (FourTree in this case) and now you can use: print(FourTree.object) and the result should be :

```
>> 4
```